# Knowing $M_{\beta}(f)$ and the base $\beta$, how can I calculate $M_{{{\beta}_k}^*}(f^*)$

Tags: matrices, dual-spaces

Let we have an endomorphism $f:\mathbb{R^3\to\mathbb{R^3}}$ and the base $\beta=${$(-1,1,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,1)$}. Let's suppose that the associated matrix for that base is$$
  M_{\beta}(f)=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 &1
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

If $f^*$ is the dual aplication of $f$, which is the associated matrix with $f^*$ for the canonic dual base? I mean, which is $
  M_{{{\beta}_k}^*}(f^*)$?

---

First of all I don't know if I do this is ok:

$M_{{\beta_{k}}^*}(f^*)=(M_{\beta_{k}}(f))^t$ Is this true?

If that's ok I would calculate $M_{\beta_{k}}(f)=M_{\beta}^{\beta_{k}}M_{\beta}(f)M_{\beta_{k}}^{\beta}$

Comment: Yes that’s true

Comment: And one question @OsamaGhani , why is  $M_{{\beta_{k}}^*}(f^*)=(M_{\beta_{k}}(f))^t$ true? I mean, is it by definition? or is it a theorem or..?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722282/what-is-common-between-adjoint-operator-and-transpose-of-the-matrix